# I am new to swift and I don't understand this function declaration

Tags: swift

```
public func computeAxis(var yMin yMin: Double, var yMax: Double)
```

what is a "var yMin yMin: Double" declaration?

Comment: A mistake, perhaps?

Comment: That must be old Swift code – there are no `var` parameters in Swift 3, and all argument labels by default have the same name as the parameter name, so the repeated `yMin` is redundant. If you're confused about the syntax of functions, then I would highly recommend reading [the functions section of the Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158).

Comment: Legacy code ;-)

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is Swift 2 and I am moving to Swift 3 by removing deprecations.  My problem is that inside the function the yMin parameter is modified so I think I need to have the variable changed for the caller.  So I was also wondering if this should us the parameter as inout.

Comment: If the function will change the passed variables you can use inout, though you could also simple return the values you want from the function, which tend to be simpler and easier to understand unless there are extenuating circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

It's the old Swift 2, the `var` means the `yMin` can be changed in the function (which is deprecated and Swift 3 has `inout parameter` concept) and the first `yMin` is `argument label` you should use when calling `computeAxis` function which in this case as it is the same as `parameter name` could be omitted (in the second parameter it is) and both parameters are of type `Double` and you should call the function like:

```
computeAxis(yMin: 1.2, yMax: 3.7)
```

Comment: `inout` is *not* a replacement for a `var` parameter in Swift 3 (in fact, one of the motivations for the change was to eliminate the confusion of `var` with `inout`)

Comment: Yes.  [Further reading](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160125/008245.html).

Comment: @i_am_jorf, see [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md) and I've updated my answer!